# Swift: Expand UITableViewCell height depending on the size of the UICollectionView inside it

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, cell

*Hi everyone. I started learning programming 1 month ago so please be nice if I don't explain my problem well :)*

My project is composed of a main `UITableView`. In each cell of the `UITableView`, I have a `UICollectionView` (on horizontal scrolling).

[Img 1 : Main view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKZqp.png)

The **width** of each `UICollectionViewCell` is the same as the entire `UITableViewCell`. My first problem is about **sizing the height of the `UITableViewCell`** (which will depend of the size of the `UICollectionView` itself and the size of the content on top of it).

[Img 2 : CollectionView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lF5sn.png)

This has to be done automatically. In fact, the `UICollectionViewCell`s will **not have the same height**, so when the user will scroll the `UICollectionView` horizontally, a new `UICollectionViewCell` will appear (with different height) and the height of the `UITableViewCell` will have to adapt.

The second problem I have is about sizing the `UICollectionViewCell`, in fact I will not know in advance what the height of it is going to be (the width is the same as the `UITableView`). I should import the content from a nib.

So now here is my ViewController file,

the variables:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var storedOffsets = [Int: CGFloat]()
```

the `UITableView` extension : Create the cell of the `UITableView` and set delegate of `UICollectionView` inside it

```
extension IndexVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 6 //Temp
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellCollectionView") as? CellPost {
        let post = self.posts[indexPath.row]
        cell.configureCell(post)

        return cell
    } else {
        return CellPost()
    }

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    guard let tableViewCell = cell as? CellPost else { return }

    tableViewCell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(self, forRow: indexPath.row)
    tableViewCell.collectionViewOffset = storedOffsets[indexPath.row] ?? 0
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplayingCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    guard let tableViewCell = cell as? CellPost else { return }

    storedOffsets[indexPath.row] = tableViewCell.collectionViewOffset
}
```

the part of the `UICollectionView` : Add the view from a Nib/xib to the cell

```
extension IndexVC: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 9 //Temp
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cellInCollectionView", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    if let textPostView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("textPostView", owner: self, options: nil).first as? textPostView {
        textPostView.configurePost(post.descriptionLbl)
        cell.addSubview(textPostView)
        textPostView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cell.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[view]-0-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["view":textPostView]))
        cell.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-0-[view]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["view":textPostView]))

    }

    return cell
}
```

Make the size of the cell the same as the entire `UICollectionView`

```
extension IndexVC: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSizeMake(collectionView.frame.width, collectionView.frame.height)
}
```

And I created this extension in the class dedicated for the `UITableViewCell` (not useful for the problem, but if any of you want to recreate it)

```
extension CellPost {
func setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate<D: protocol<UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>>(dataSourceDelegate: D, forRow row: Int) {

    collectionView.delegate = dataSourceDelegate
    collectionView.dataSource = dataSourceDelegate
    collectionView.tag = row
    collectionView.setContentOffset(collectionView.contentOffset, animated:false) // Stops collection view if it was scrolling.
    collectionView.reloadData()
}

var collectionViewOffset: CGFloat {
    set {
        collectionView.contentOffset.x = newValue
    }

    get {
        return collectionView.contentOffset.x
    }
}
```

If anyone want to use this code, it works great, but I have to hardcode the height of the `UITableView` with a `tableView( ... heightForRowAtIndexPath ...)`

I tried everything to make the `UITableViewCell` adapt to what's inside it (I tried calculating the size of content sent by the Nib I'm putting in the cell, and then send it to `tableView( ... heightForRowAtIndexPath ...)`
but I can't make it work. I also tried Auto Layouts but maybe I'm doing it wrong. I also think the problem could come from the part that I imported the nib in my cell.

I also have no idea of a way to expand the cell after the user has swiped the `UICollectionViewCell`, is there any way to create an event when that happens? And maybe call `tableView( ... heightForRowAtIndexPath ...)` again?

Comment: seldom use it in this way, when you decide to use UICollectionView, in most case, there is no need to use UITableView to contain it I think.

Comment: @Jean Baptiste, Did the accepted answer solve your problem? I am doing exactly the same as your code but when I use UITableViewAutomaticDimension my collection view doesn't bind at all. could you give me a hint please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understanding you need to auto adjust tableview cell height. so you can use autolayout for adjust cell height.

Write in ViewDidLoad

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Before Returning cell in CellForRowAtIndexPath

```
self.tableView.setNeedsLayout()
self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

You can find link for autolayout.
[enter link description here](http://candycode.io/automatically-resizing-uitableviewcells-with-dynamic-text-height-using-auto-layout/)

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve my problem, I created an array to store the height of each cell of the `UITableView` (named `cellHeight`).

I also calculate the height of each cell at the start of the program in an array composed of array (named `cellHeightForPost`). The main array represent all the `TableView cells`, each array inside it represent the height of each cell of the 'collectionView'

In order to **update** the table view everytime I change the collectionView inside it, i used the fonction `collectionView(... willDiplayCell...)` :

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
cellHeight[collectionView.tag] = cellHeightForPost[collectionView.tag][indexPath.row]
self.tableView.setNeedsLayout()
self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

My **UITableView size** is defined in `tableView(... heightForRowAtIndexPath)` and `tableView(... estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath)` :

```
return cellHeight[indexPath.row]
```

To set the **size** of the `collectionViewCells` :

```
return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: cellHeightForPost[collectionView.tag][indexPath.row])
```