# Dynamic height for a UITableView based on a dynamic collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have to add a `UICollectionView` inside a `UITableViewCell`.
The `collectionView` can have a different number of items.
So the `collectionView` should adjust properly inside the `tableView`.

I have implemented this inside my Project:
https://github.com/vishalwaka/DynamicCollectionViewInsideTableViewCell

In my case, the height of the cell is not being the adjusted after the height of the `collectionView` is set.

How can I set the `collectionView` to not be scrollable and also show all content inside the `tableviewcell`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dynamically change the height of a UITableView Cell containing a UICollectionView cell in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45176747/how-to-dynamically-change-the-height-of-a-uitableview-cell-containing-a-uicollec?rq=1)

Comment: @Sateesh I have to use the collection view cells of different width, so I can not calculate how many rows will be there.

Comment: please share the some sample code.

Comment: @Sateesh It is in the shared GitHub project.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42437966/how-to-adjust-height-of-uicollectionview-to-be-the-height-of-the-content-size-of) ?

Answer (score 7):

Create a `collectionView` inside `UITableViewCell` with Leading, Trailing, Top, Bottom, Height constraint like this:

[image]

Now, in your `tableViewCell` class make a `NSKeyValueObserver` and add this on `UICollectionView`'s **contentSize** property and assign contentSize changes to collectionView's height constraint.

```
class FormCollectionTableViewCell: UITableViewCell{

  var collectionViewObserver: NSKeyValueObservation?

  override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    addObserver()
  }

  override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        layoutIfNeeded()
  }

  func addObserver() {
       collectionViewObserver = collectionView.observe(\.contentSize, changeHandler: { [weak self] (collectionView, change) in
            self?.collectionView.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
            self?.collectionViewHrightConstarint.constant = collectionView.contentSize.height
            self?.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }
   deinit {
      collectionViewObserver = nil
   }
}
```

And in your viewController class use the following code:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Now, your table view will have collection view with dynamic height. Don't forgot to disable scrolling of `UICollectionView` and adjusting it's flow.

Comment: I am getting a constraint break when specifying the height in advance. And after changing the constraint to be of low priority, the collection view is not having proper height. Can you share your project?

Comment: collectionView.contentSize.height is setting the height properly, but it is not expanding or shrinking the cell height after that.

Comment: @vishalwaka: are you setting priority of height constraint equal to 1000 and implementing viewDidLayoutSubviews in your viewController class. For me it is working fine.

Comment: all the `layoutIfNeeded` are not really necessary and shouldn't be needed.

Comment: @nikksindia For a height constraint of 1000, the constraint will start breaking. I have implemented viewDidLayoutSubviews in my viewController class. I have updated the code at https://github.com/vishalwaka/DynamicCollectionViewInsideTableViewCell . Also there are sometimes views not updating properly.

Comment: I have tried this as well and it's not working for me. Loading my data from Firebase Storage.

Answer (score 0):

Create the following subclass of a collectionView:

```
class IntrinsicSizeCollectionView: UICollectionView {

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.setup()
}

override init(frame: CGRect, collectionViewLayout layout: UICollectionViewLayout) {
    super.init(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)

    self.setup()
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    if !self.bounds.size.equalTo(self.intrinsicContentSize) {
        self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }
}

override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    get {
        let intrinsicContentSize = self.contentSize
        return intrinsicContentSize
    }
}

func setup() {
    self.isScrollEnabled = false
    self.bounces = false
}
```

Add the collectionView to a tableViewCell and set its constraints leading, trailing, top, bottom to the bounds of the cell. Also set the intrinsic size as in the screenshot.

[image]

The size of the tableViewCell should set to the UITableViewAutomaticdimension and also an estimatedHeight for this cell should be set in the dataSource of the TableView.

That should be all.

Comment: Even after making these changes, I am getting the same issue. Sometimes the cell is not expanded as the content of the collection view changes. Also, the shrinking is not happening the properly.

Comment: Can you share your project?

Answer (score 0):

After checking your project I suggest you use a slightly different approach.

After updating the model, you can ask the collection view layout what the new content size will be ([collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617796-collectionviewcontentsize)). You then update the height constraint constant.

So, you should:

1. update your model
2. reload the row
3. ask the layout for its new `contentSize`
4. update the height constraint constant

This modification in your project should achieve this:

```
// Remove the content size observing logic.

func configureForVehicle(_ vehicle: Vehicle, selectedHouseType: String) {
    self.vehicle = vehicle

    applianceCollectionView.reloadData()

    // Set the height constraint to the new value, found in the layout's content size info.
    // Since the model (self.vehicle) was already updated, the layout will return the new content size.
    // Because this is all happening while the cell is being reloaded, the cell will also resize properly.
    // You don't need to perform any other setNeedsLayout/layoutIfNeeded calls.
    self.applianceCollectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = applianceCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
}
```

Note the comment about not needing any additional layout update calls. Only calling
 `tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)` should be enough. Unnecessary layout updates can cause a performance hit.

---

As a side note there is another approach you can use if you wish to **animate the height change without reloading the cell**. In this case you would need to keep/find a reference to the cell you wish to update then do the following:

1. Update the model for the cell without calling any table view reload calls.
2. Reload the collection view on the updated cell.
3. Update the height constraint same way as above.
4. Use a callback of some sort to notify your table view that a cell wishes to update its height.
5. In the callback call `tableView.beginUpdates(); tableView.endUpdates()`. This causes the tableView to re-layout its cells and animate height changes.

From [beginUpdates() documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614908-beginupdates):

> You can also use this method followed by the endUpdates() method to animate the change in the row heights without reloading the cell. This group of methods must conclude with an invocation of endUpdates().

Comment: The solution you have suggested is not working for me. Can you check it once by updating the project on your machine?

Comment: Your project works for me if I do the following:

 1. Remove the `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` override from `ViewController` and `layoutSubviews()` override in `ApplianceTableViewCell`
 2. Remove the content size observer in `ApplianceTableViewCell`
 3. Implement the code from my answer in `ApplianceTableViewCell`

Comment: EDIT: After checking again I noticed the `applianceCollectionView.reloadData()` was necessary after all. Edited my answer.